# How to use declared variable in query

Tags: oracle, plsql

I want to get count of records in specific partition.
The returned value will be used later in the flow.

```
DECLARE  
  pt VARCHAR2(20);
  countr NUMBER;
BEGIN
  pt:='61';
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(pt);

 SELECT COUNT(*) INTO countr FROM T1 PARTITION ( pt) ;

END;
```

But getting error, it doesn't replace 'pt' with the assigned value.

Comment: You would have to use dynamic SQL to specify a partition name at run time (or a table name, or column name, etc.). But how is the table partitioned - why not filter on the partition range/interval instead? And `'61'` doesn't look like a valid partition name, as it doesn't meet the object naming rules.

Comment: 61 is not real name, i wrote from my head... I need to see if partition has data if not, to exit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use variables to specify object names (tables, columns, partition etc.) in static SQL.

You need to use dynamic SQL, e.g. with a non-quoted partition name:

```
DECLARE  
  pt all_tab_partitions.partition_name%TYPE;
  countr NUMBER;
BEGIN
  pt:='p61';
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(pt);

  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM T1 PARTITION (' || pt || ')'
  INTO countr ;
END;
/
```

If you have quoted identifiers for the partition names you need to include the quotes in the statement, and make sure the case of the partition name matches exactly:

```
DECLARE  
  pt all_tab_partitions.partition_name%TYPE;
  countr NUMBER;
BEGIN
  pt:='61';
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(pt);

  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM T1 PARTITION ("' || pt || '")'
  INTO countr ;
END;
/
```